# Forcing template function instantiation in class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function that is declared like:

```
template<typename T>
void MyFunction();
```

And a class:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:

    typedef void (*Function_T)();
    Function_T m_Func;
    void DoSomething()
    {
        m_Func = &MyFunction<T>;
    }
}
```

When I use the class, I undefined symbols error on `MyFunction<T>`.
If I change `DoSomething` to

```
void DoSomething()
{
    m_Func = &MyFunction<T>;
    return;
    MyFunction<T>();
}
```

Everything works, but that looks like a workaround and will probably not work with optimization.
I cannot add

```
template void MyFunction<T>;
```

to the class because it says it cannot be in class. Is there any other way I can force instantiation of the function?

Edit:
I was able to write a test that fails, but in g++ it has a different message and actually a compiler error: http://ideone.com/RbMnh

Comment: Does `MyFunction` have a body?

Comment: @AJG85: it does in the same place, but its not relavent for the question.

Comment: What compiler and version? Have you realized that `Function_T` is not a function pointer but rather a `void*`? Is the definition of `MyFunction` available at the place of instantiation?

Comment: @Dani: Whether the definition is or not present at the place of instantiation of the `MyClass` template is very relevant. If you provide only the declaration, the compiler will trust that you will instantiate the function at some later point (it cannot instantiate it there), and that in turn means that it will create the dependency but not the symbol

Comment: Compiler is Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn), the Function_T is just a copy error, and MyFunction body is in the same file and before the class.

Comment: Maybe `friend void MyFunction<T>();` could help? But I thought that taking the address should be enough to force instantiation, so the friend declaration might not help either.

Comment: @Sjoerd: The friend declaration will not force the instantiation. Taking the address of the function should, but does not seem to do it, but this could very well be a compiler bug...

Comment: That edit shows a different error, it does not even **compile**, so it cannot be a problem with *undefined symbols*. Use your own compiler, reduce the problem to the bare minimum that reproduces it and show that code...

Comment: @David Rodríguez: on my compiler its a linker error...

Comment: A simpler example that reproduces the error: http://ideone.com/MRaB0

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work with optimization as well. Although, I don't know why simply `m_Func = &MyFunction<T>` doesn't work. [GCC 4.3.4 compiles it fine](http://ideone.com/l3cj8). Which compiler you're using?

And you can also do this:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    if ( false) MyFunction<T>();
    m_Func = &MyFunction<T>;
    return;
}
```

By the way, the function pointer type is incorrectly defined. It should be this:

```
typedef void (*Function_T)();
                     //   ^^ put this!
```

Comment: That would probably be subject to the same optimization problems that he was worried about, wouldn't it?

Comment: The function pointer is copy error. I'm using clang compiler.

Comment: I have tried with clang++ 2.8 release 28 and it compiles and links perfectly, what exact version of the compiler are you using? Can you create a minimal full program that exhibits the behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Your code compiles fine for me using GCC, so I'm not sure if this solution solves your particular problem, but you can explicitly instantiate template functions like so:

```
// Template function defined:
template <typename T>
void MyFunction() {
    // body
}

// Template function instantiated:
template void MyFunction<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be either a compiler bug, or an error in the parts of the code that you are not showing. Try to build a minimal example that reproduces the problem, this is the minimal example that I have been able to produce, and compiles fine with both clang++ 2.8 and g++ 4.4/4.5:

```
drodriguez@drodriguez-desktop:/tmp$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void function() {
}

template <typename T>
struct type {
    typedef void (*Func)();
    Func _f;
    void f() {
        _f = &function<T>;
    }
};

int main() {
    type<int> t;
    t.f();
    std::cout << t._f << std::endl;
}
drodriguez@drodriguez-desktop:/tmp$ /usr/bin/clang++ --version
clang version 2.8 (branches/release_28)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
drodriguez@drodriguez-desktop:/tmp$ /usr/bin/clang++ -o test test.cpp && ./test
1
drodriguez@drodriguez-desktop:/tmp$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

drodriguez@drodriguez-desktop:/tmp$ g++-4.4 -o test test.cpp && ./test
1
```

Comment: @Dani: That is a completely different error, and it is due to the fact that the types don't match `&C<T>` has type `void (*)(int)` and you are trying to cast it into `void (*)()`, the error can be misleading but if you fix the cast (which is the contextual information that is missing) then the error will go away (well, it will be transformed into another error as the argument does not match the type of the receiving end... http://ideone.com/Fh0Nx

Comment: @Dani that must be a bug in the compiler. I have just verified with clang++ 3.0 in MacOSX and it does trigger a linker error, but it should not have compiled... at any rate there you have the solution: correct the cast. That, and try not to *fix* the problem while rewriting your problem as a question :)